# Prototype's weird supported environment check

Tags: javascript, dom, prototypejs

I was looking at the PrototypeJS code and found this check -

```
var div = document.createElement('div'),
      form = document.createElement('form'),
      isSupported = false;    
if (div['__proto__'] && (div['__proto__'] !== form['__proto__'])) {
    isSupported = true;
}
```

I would like to know what are the cases where this condition returns false -

```
div['__proto__'] !== form['__proto__']
```

Note: The function's comment says - "Used internally to detect if the browser supports extending html element prototypes". Not sure how this check helps for that.

Answer (score 0):

This test allows PrototypeJS to figure out if it can add specific methods to specific types of element prototypes.

For example you would not want the method [`getInputs()`](http://api.prototypejs.org/dom/Form/prototype/getInputs/) (which returns an array of all of the form's elements) on a `<div>` element because it would only make sense being used on a `<form>` element.

HTML

```
<div id='mydiv'></div>
<form id='myform'></form>
```

JS

```
$('mydiv').addClassName('newclass');  //does not error
$('myform').addClassName('newclass'); //does not error

$('myform').getInputs();              //does not error
$('mydiv').getInputs();               //throws error 'has no method getInputs()'
```

Example on JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/C39gu/

Comment: Thanks for explaining Prototype's motive. So, it does it to check if form element is different from div element's prototype to add methods specific to each element type. But can you also tell me if there is any known environment where this condition fails or is it just precautionary check by Prototype.

Comment: That is actually a good question, and this is a theory, I believe it is because PrototypeJS supports a large set of browsers even older browsers (IE6, IE7) there might be a condition where that happens and the code checks for it.